# Can BFAST algorithm be applied to to a whole study area/ ROI?

Tags: r, remote-sensing, landsat, time-series, bfast

I am working on identification of breakpoints in Landsat based NDVI time series (1990-2018). I am using The Breaks for Additive Seasonal and Trend (BFAST) algorithm which is a pixel based time series decomposition method to detect and characterise abrupt changes. I wonder would it be possible to apply it for a region of interest or study area as a whole instead of applying it on selected pixels?

```
ndvi_stack <- stack(ndvi_list)
ndvi_ROI_1 <- crop(ndvi_stack, extent(ROI_1))
ndvi_ROI_1
```

So, ndvi_ROI_1 is a study area or region of interest. Now I select the pixel:

```
selected_pixel <- 100
```

I created an irregular time series for the selected pixel (100 in this case) using bfastts() from BFAST package.

```
(s <- bfastts(as.vector(ndvi_ROI_1[selected_pixel]), dates, type = c("irregular")))
```

The time series is converted to a regular time series using advice from https://philippgaertner.github.io/2018/04/bfast-preparation/.

I also tried not to select to a specific pixel and run bfastts() on whole study region and it seems to work (although I am not sure about the validity of results). I used the following code:

```
(s <- bfastts(as.vector(ndvi_ROI_1), dates, type = c("irregular")))
```

I am still not sure if this is technically right to apply bfast method to a whole study region instead of pixel by pixel basis? And if it is, is the coding correct or I have to introduce any other steps?

Looking forward to the kind advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used BFAST for my thesis some years ago, and this is the code I used. Given the age of this code, things may have changed significantly, to make specific elements not function entirely any more, but the process of creating a function to apply BFAST and then applying that function on the raster is still a good way to approach the problem. Do note that the processing time can become lengthy.
It should be noted that I preprocessed my data into a regular smooth time-series before utilizing R.

One key thing that seems to have changed may be that the function that used to be named `ts` is now `bfastts`, but I haven't checked if the syntax is the same as it was.

```
library(bfast)
library(raster)
library(gtools)
vegevi <- brick("evi_subset_brick.grd") # loads my regular EVI data into a raster-brick. EVI is just a different vegetation index, that is more suited for areas with a high vegetation density than NDVI.

xbfast <- function(data) {  
  ndvi <- ts(data, frequency=46, start=1) # adjust the frequency to match yours
  result <- bfast(ndvi, season="harmonic", max.iter=2, breaks=1)
  niter <- length(result$output)
  out <- result$output[[niter]]
  bp <- out$Wt.bp #breakpoint of the seasonality component
  st <- out$St #the seasonality component
  st_a <- st[1:bp] #seasonality untill the breakpoint
  st_b <- st[bp:460] #hard coded end-point - should likely be changed to something better
  st_amin <- min(st_a)
  st_amax <- max(st_a)
  st_bmin <- min(st_b)
  st_bmax <- max(st_b)
  st_adif <- st_amax - st_amin
  st_bdif <- st_bmax - st_bmin
  st_dif <- st_bdif - st_adif
  Magni<-result$Magnitude #magnitude of the biggest change detected in the trend component
  Timing<-result$Time #timing of the biggest change detected in the trend component
  return(c(st_dif,bp,Magni,Timing)) 
}

bfastfun <- function(y) {
  percNA <- apply(y, 1, FUN=function(x) (sum(is.na(x))/length(x)) )
  i <- (percNA<0.2)
  res <- matrix(NA, length(i), 4) #
  if (sum(i) > 0) {
    res <- t(apply(y[i,], 1, xbfast))
  }
  return(res)
}

bfast_output <- calc(vegevi, fun=bfastfun)

diff <- subset(bfast_output, 1)
time <- subset(bfast_output, 2)
magn <- subset(bfast_output, 3)
magn_time <- subset(bfast_output, 4)

writeRaster(diff, filename="evi_diff.tif", format="GTiff")
writeRaster(time, filename="evi_diff_time.tif", format="GTiff")
writeRaster(magn, filename="evi_magni.tif", format="GTiff")
writeRaster(magn_time, filename="evi_magni_timing.tif", format="GTiff")
```

Comment: Dear Mikkel, thank you very much for sharing your code. My time series data is irregular therefore I can't use ts() function. I have to convert irregular time series to a regular first and then aggregate to regular monthly time series. My aggregated monthly time series is: s.m.periodic <- aggregate.daily.to.monthly(s.d.periodic)                                                                   
 I am not sure how can I amend your code to complete remaining steps. Should I run xbfast & bfastfun functions as it is & only replace vegevi in bfast_output with my raster brick? Appreciate your help.

Comment: @SAKhan - yes, if you have a monthly time-series, then you can go right ahead and replace my 'vegevi' with your own raster brick.